# Owl carousel - stylize differently the dots from the navigation

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I used Owl Carousel 2 beta and I would like to stylize differently (size and color) the dots from the slider navigation.

Like that :

[image]

Unfortunately I have this :

[image]

I tried this code :

```
<div class="owl-dots">
     <div class="first owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
     <div class="second owl-dot"><span></span></div>
     <div class="third owl-dot"><span></span></div>
</div>

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.first span {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.first:hover span,
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.first .active  span {
    background-color: #00c0f1;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.second span {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.second:hover span, 
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.second .active span {
    background-color: #add036;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.third span {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.third:hover span,
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.third .active span {
    background-color: #ec2426;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On all your css, selectors for the owl-dot class should be

```
.owl-dot.first.active // remove the space you have between .active and .first
```

Also, what exactly is wrong with what you're getting? You can't change the size or you can't change the color on active state?

Comment: Thank you for the jsFiddle, unfortunately that's don't work when I use for example
 .owl-dot.first span {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}

I must add owl.theme and owl.dots

Comment: Right, I wasn't suggesting to change your selectors. More specificity is always better.  However, I am still unsure of what you are looking for this to do aside from what is being done in the fiddle?